# Is it a fallacy to have a 'tester goal'?

Tags: maven, testing, maven-2

Well, I would like to have a maven goal `execute-custom-tests` inside my `custom-maven-plugin` that consists of running test methods (This tests are not unit tests). Something similar to `test` goal of `soapui-pro-maven-plugin`, for example.

Why? Basically the main objectives of the plugin are testing stuff (not unit testing) and the tests in `src/test` are for unit testing, right?

Being more specific I was thinking about something like this:

```
@Mojo (name = "run-custom-tests",  LifecyclePhase.TEST)
public class TesterMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(property = "someParameter")
  private String someParameter;

  // [...] parameters for test configuration

  @Override
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    // Piece of code that executes a set of custom tests which procedure I specified. 
  }

}
```

When test fail, I would like them to be marked as failed tests not as failed executions. What's the right thing to do here? Show me the light, please.

Comment: More details could be helpful but it doesn't sound crazy for me: maven is "convention over configuration" and if you have to configure surefire a lot, something is not good IMO

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Why not using failsafe ?

Answer (score 0):

Maven conventions support two types of testing out of the box: unit tests (via maven-surefire-plugin) and integration tests (via maven-failsafe-plugin).

By default, maven-surefire-plugin [only looks for the following files](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) with unit tests:

- **/Test*.java
- **/*Test.java
- **/*TestCase.java

Similarly, [default includes for integration tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) run by  maven-failsafe-plugin are the following:

- **/IT*.java
- **/*IT.java
- **/*ITCase.java

So, as you can see, Maven lets each plugin figure out which tests it should care about. So it's perfectly fine for `src/test/java` to contain different types of tests, not just unit tests.

### Different folder

You can put tests in a different folder too. One example would be if you have non-Java tests, since then `src/test/java` location doesn't make sense. Standard Maven plugins get project model from Maven to figure out the `src/test/java` location and some 3rd party plugins use the same mechanism. Depending on the plugin you use, you might want to check out its configuration or use maven-build-helper-plugin to [add-test-source](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) in order for some plugins to pick up another test folder automatically.

### Different tests on demand

From the Maven perspective the core difference between unit tests and integration tests is the additional requirements for the later: they often need to have your project already packaged and they often need additional setup or teardown. But you yourself can set up multiple test goals during both test and integration-test phases. All major test frameworks support specifying which test suite should be run when (e.g., via [groups](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups)). If your framework doesn't, you can still use plugin includes/excludes. It is a standard practice to combine this with [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in order to only run smoke tests by default (during development) and to run full tests on CI environment. You can use the same approach to enable anyone (a tester?) to run extra tests on demand, e.g., to run extra heavy tests when certain important part of the code has changed.